# Можете объяснить суть invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть основной поток, в котором я создаю все `Controls` в winforms. И есть второй поток, который вызывается через срабатывание события. В результате этого события мне нужно изменить значение `DataSource` у `DataGridView`. В результате возникает ошибка, что доступ к контролу пытается получить не основной поток, в котором был создан контрол. 
Решением является использование методов `Invoke\BeginInvoke`. Но саму суть я не понимаю этих методов и как их реализовать в коде.
В создаваемом втором потоке используется функция доступа к `dgv`

```
private void RefreshTables()
{
    try
    {
        if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        sql = "select rowid, * from OpenPos";
        adapOpenPos = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
        dsOpenPos = new DataSet();
        adapOpenPos.Fill(dsOpenPos);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsOpenPos.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Update();
        con.Close();

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        sql = "select rowid, * from ClosePos";
        adapClosePos = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
        dsClosePos = new DataSet();
        adapClosePos.Fill(dsClosePos);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dsClosePos.Tables[0];
        dataGridView2.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView2.Columns[14].Visible = false;
        dataGridView2.Update();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Суть метода `Invoke` довольно проста - он принимает делегат и выполняет его в том потоке, в котором был создан элемент управления, у которого вызывается `Invoke`. Как вы могли заметить, если обращаться к контролам в *WinForms* не из того потока, в котором они были созданы, будет выброшено исключение. Соответственно, метод `Invoke` полезен в случаях, когда необходимо работать с контролом из других потоков. Метод `BeginInvoke` делает то же самое, но асинхронно.

Небольшой пример использования `Invoke`:

```
private void ButtonInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myThread = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
    myThread.Start(); //метод выполняется в другом потоке
}

private void ThreadFunction()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Action action = () => listBox1.Items.Add("value");
    // Свойство InvokeRequired указывает, нeжно ли обращаться к контролу с помощью Invoke
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}
```

Стоит также отметить, что `async/await`, добавленные в C# 5, позволяют обойтись без `Invoke`:

```
private async void ButtonAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("first");
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    });
    // этот код будет продолжен в UI потоке, 
    // и здесь нет необходимости использовать Invoke
    listBox1.Items.Add("second");
}
```

Comment: @Fresto да, в целом так

Comment: Т.е. грубо говоря, если мне нужно изменить `datagridview` в другом потоке, я в своём первоначальном коде изменяю контрол с помощью Invoke и делегата.
`Action action = () => dataGridView1.DataSource = dsOpenPos.Tables[0];
if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
`

Comment: @Fresto не только изменить ваш контрол, но и вообще работать с ним из другого потока

Comment: я вас понял, сейчас попробую сделать и отпишусь

Comment: получается, также я должен проделать с любыми переменными, которые задействуются в другом потоке?

Comment: @Fresto не с переменными, а именно с контролами. Они спроектированы так, что работать с ними можно только из того, потока, в котором были созданы. Обычных переменных  это не касается. Переменные вы можете захватывать разными потоками (но это отдельная большая тема, почитайте о ней)

Answer (score 10):

В оконных приложениях Windows существует так называемый *поток пользовательского интерфейса* (UI thread), по сути — основной поток приложения, создаваемый самым первым.

Он выполняет обработку оконных сообщений (Windows messages), вызывая в цикле функции `GetMessage` или `PeekMessage`. Если вы хотите что-то сделать с пользовательским интерфейсом, например, изменить строку в поле ввода, вы посылаете ему оконное сообщение.

В WinForms изменение текста в поле ввода выполняется с помощью присваивания:

```
textBox1.Text = "Новый текст";
```

но на низком уровне этот код приводит к отсылке оконного сообщения `WM_SETTEXT` окну с дескриптором `textbox1.Handle` при помощи функции `SendMessage`.

Тонкость заключается в том, что отправив сообщение, вы можете захотеть получить результат. Это неочевидно для `WM_SETTEXT`, но для `WM_GETTEXT` вы точно захотите узнать ответ.

И это означает, что если вы вызвали `SendMessage`, вы обязаны дождаться завершения функции. Это не представляет большой проблемы, если вы вызываете `SendMessage`, когда у вас всего один поток, потому что `SendMessage` вызывает обработчик, который, как правило, обрабатывает оконное сообщение достаточно быстро.

Но что, если вы вызовете `SendMessage` из другого потока? Вопреки расхожему мнению, это не приведёт к ошибке. Вы можете это сделать, но вызывающий поток будет остановлен до тех пор, пока `SendMessage` не завершится. Если в программе работают несколько потоков, и они захотят что-то изменить в пользовательском интерфейсе, они будут приостановлены, и каждый их `SendMessage` будет выполняться основным потоком последовательно.

В современной оконной программе вы почти наверняка не работаете с потоками напрямую, а используете абстракцию более высокого уровня: асинхронные функции обратного вызова. В .NET вы можете использовать удобную обёртку, которая называется TPL и предоставляет вам классы `Task` и `Task<TResult>`, чтобы не приходилось разбираться с асинхронными функциями.

Асинхронные функции работают поверх потоков. Для их работы .NET создаёт несколько потоков в пуле, каждый из которых висит в бесконечном цикле и ждёт сигналов от вашего приложения. Как только возникает сигнал, какой-то поток из пула выполняет вашу функцию обратного вызова и снова засыпает.

И всё бы хорошо, но часто такие небольшие функции что-то хотят сделать с вашим пользовательским интерфейсом. Например, вы обрабатываете большой файл и просите Windows вызывать вашу функцию, когда будут прочитаны очередные 64Кб. Блок прочитан, Windows будит поток и передаёт ему вашу функцию на выполнение. Функция делает полезную работу, а потом хочет увеличить индикатор процесса. Она вызывает `SendMessage`, который может конфликтовать с другими асинхронными функциями.

А если асинхронные функции начинают ждать друг друга, соответствующие потоки оказываются заняты, и программе, которая заведует пулом потоков, приходится создавать новые.

Это проблема, так что Windows запрещает вызывать `SendMessage` из других потоков при асинхронных вызовах.

Возникает вопрос, как эту проблему решить. Разработчики Windows предлагают разбить вашу асинхронную функцию на две. Первая делает полезную работу и потом говорит пулу потоков: вызови вот эту вот вторую асинхронную функцию, но сделай это в основном потоке. Вторая функция обновляет индикатор процесса, и, поскольку пул потоков вызывает её в основном потоке, никаких конфликтов не происходит.

Да, обновление интерфейса всё ещё происходит последовательно, но все остальные асинхронные функции совершенно не мешают друг другу.

Для того, чтобы выполнить функцию в потоке пользовательского интерфейса разработчики WinForms предоставили методы `Invoke` и `BeginInvoke`.

Использовать их можно, например, так:

```
if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
sql = "select rowid, * from OpenPos";
adapOpenPos = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
dsOpenPos = new DataSet();
adapOpenPos.Fill(dsOpenPos);

// здесь соединение можно закрыть, потому что метод `adapOpenPos.Fill`
// уже загрузил данные
con.Close();

if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsOpenPos.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Update();
    });
}
else
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dsOpenPos.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

Здесь параметр `Invoke` это *анонимный делегат*, то есть в действительности функция, которая будет вызвана из потока пользовательского интерфейса.

Есть несколько способов упростить этот код (ищите на Stack Overflow). Отмечу основную идею: код располагается внутри одного из методов вашей формы, соответственно, `InvokeRequired` и `Invoke` это свойство и метод формы.

Вызывать изменение свойств через `Invoke` нужно только в том случае, когда свойство `InvokeRequired` истинно. Перед вызовом полезно подготовить все данные, которые вам потребуется использовать, чтобы не тормозить поток пользовательского интерфейса. Сначала готовите данные, а потом присваиваете их через свойства элементов управления внутри `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` — таков основной паттерн асинхронного программирования десктопных приложений.

Answer (score 4):

Я попробую ответить как можно проще для понимания, так сказать в дополнение к другим ответам.

Создавая новый поток Вы ему передаете некий код, который должен будет выполниться в этом новом потоке. Для примера при создании через Task это выглядело бы так.

```
new Task(() => 
{
    //тут код, который выполнится в новом потоке    
}).Start();
```

Метод Invoke же служит наоборот окошком в основной поток, в остальном он объявляется почти точно так же.

```
new Task(() => 
{
    //побочный поток

    this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        //это окошко обратно в главный поток
        //код написанный тут выполнится в главном потоке не вызывая ошибок
    }));

    //дальше идет снова побочный поток

}).Start();
```

Изменение свойств и вызов методов контролов должен проходить в главном потоке и оборачиваться Invoke.

---

Есть еще один способ, который иногда использую я, это касается изменений после основных операций. Может пригодится когда-нибудь и Вам, я его использую для блокировки/разблокировки интерфейса на время операций.

```
Task task = new Task(() => 
{ 
    //основные операции
});

task.ContinueWith(_ => 
{
    //обновление контролов, будет вызвано после выполнения предыдущего кода
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

task.Start();
```

Comment: Как-то сложно работа с task написана. Не лучше ли использовать `await Task.Run(() => ...)`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, лучше, но код писался в студии сразу, а у меня там проекты на четвертом фреймворке из-за поддержки WinXP.