# Сообщение пользователю из второстепенного потока без его остановки

Tags: c#, winforms, асинхронность, messagebox

C#, Windows Forms.

Есть главная форма, есть второстепенный поток, который в какой-то момент должен вывести сообщение пользователю и при этом продолжить работу, не ожидая реакции пользователя. Проблема, собственно, в выводе сообщения.

Хочется обойтись "малой кровью" и не создавать свою форму, и применить MessageBox. (Это не категорическое пожелание, просто не могу придумать ничего "малокровнее".)
Для этого объявил делегат, в главной форме определил его тело. Дальше осталось применить метод BeginInvoke()... только что-то запутался :-)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()    
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Data.Call_Msg_SomeMsg = new Data.Void_Dlg_Void(Msg_SomeMsg);

        }

        void Msg_SomeMsg()
        {
            MessageBox ... BeginInvoke ... ?
        }
    }


    public static partial class Data
    {
        public delegate void Void_Dlg_Void();
        public static Void_Dlg_Void Call_Msg_SomeMsg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Примеры использования Invoke можно посмотреть здесь, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679560/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-invoke

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Msg_SomeMsg()
{
    Invoke(new Action(() => {
        MessageBox.Show(...);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за четкий ответ! 
Проверил, при BeginInvoke все работает как мне надо! Бокс выскакивает, вторичный поток продолжает работу.
Спасибо!